# SOLUCIONAR FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, agrupación, reporte

Buen dia
Tengo un problema en el despliegue de mi pdf con FPDF, resulta que inicializo una variable llamada $productTotal=0, al principio del while recorre el primer registro y como tengo una funcion isset el cual si la variable $productTotal=0 no la muestre, mi ultima fila del recorrido no le coloca el valor de monto otorgado sino que hace un salto al otro grupo anidado, mejor les dejo unas imagenes para que puedan comprender y me puedan ayudar a encontrar una solucion, he realizado varias pruebas pero ninguna me resulta, habra alguien que ya se haya topado con este problema, de antemano muchas gracias..
Nota: Lo de color naranja debe contener lo del recuadro rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de ese segmento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podría ser que la función `report_product_total()` la deberías llamar después de establecer la información del grupo?, es decir, de esta manera:
`$pdf->Cell(20, 3, $row['gr_grupo'] . ' - ' . $row['gr_nombre']);
$pdf->Ln();
report_product_total($pdf, $productTotal);`

Comment: Ya lo he probado pero continua dandome el mismo problema....:(

Comment: Hola. Por aportar una idea. Comprueba en qué casos la variable `$row['desembolso']` vale cero. ¿Puede ser justo antes de la última pasada de cada grupo...?

Comment: Te refieres a realizar esta validacion: if(isset($productTotal)){
    $productTotal += $row['desembolso'];
    } si es asi, ya la he realizado y ni aun funciona....:(